# Where am I addressing memory I do not own? (char array)

Tags: c, arrays, char

The aim of this program is to print every word on an own line with number of line and word. It compiles just fine without warnings, but it seems like I´m addressing memory I do not own somewhere since I am getting me`Abort trap:6`, but I don´t know where and why. I have looked up other questions with the same error, but the answers there didn´t help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int word = 1, line = 1, a = 0;
    char str[1], w[70];
    strcpy(w, " ");
    while (a != EOF)
    {
        a = getchar();
        if ((a != EOF) && (a == ' ' || a == '\t' || a == '\n'))
        {
            ++word;
            if (a == '\n')
                ++line;
        }
        if (a != EOF && a != ' ' && a != '\t' && a != '\n')
            sprintf(str, "%d", a);
        strcat(w, str);
        if (a == ' ' || a == '\t' || a == '\n' || a == EOF)
        {
            printf("\n %d.%d%s", line, word, w);
            strcpy(w, " ");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code. It is very hard to read.

Comment: `sprintf(str, "%d", a);` while `str` is of length of one is definitely writing memory you don't own.

Comment: `char str[1];` can hold a string of length `0` .

Comment: Indentation is missing. It is hard to see whats included in an  `if` block and whats not.

Comment: @FantasyCookie17 You think so? Then take a look around at the other C questions and see how the code is usually formatted.

Comment: Writing code for a living also means *reading* code to modify/debug it. Formatting code so that its structure is immediately visible makes that much, much, easier.

Comment: Put newlines at the end of printing operations, not at the beginning.

Comment: @Osiris @EugeneSh. Now I don´t get the error anymore, but it will print `2.2 116101115116116` if I type "test" for some reason, which means that i is not converted to a string the way I want it to, but that is probably a topic for another question, as long as nobody wants to give me a quick answer here.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why would that be necessary? I think there was a reason I did that, although I can´t remember.

Comment: The second and third comments are giving a clear "quick answer". You are writing into a string which cannot hold any character as it has a space for the null-terminator only.

Comment: `sprintf(str, "%d", a);` You are printing the ascii value in `str`. I think you want to use `sprintf(str, "%c", a);`.

Comment: @Osiris: even `sprintf(str, "%c", a);` is going to write out of bounds (though I agree `%d` writes further out of bouds — but any writing out of bounds is bad!).

Comment: You write out of bounds with the lines `char str[1], w[70];` and `strcpy(w, " ");` — it puts a space and a null in `str`, but `str` can only hold one character, so you've got undefined behaviour (UB) there immediately. You also write out of bounds with `sprintf(str, "%d", a);` — more UB. What else goes wrong, I'm not sure, but this is the start of trouble.  Maybe use `char str[16];` instead of `char str[1];` — that should be a mild case of overkill, but it should avoid writing out of bounds.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes i totally agree, i only thought since he wrote that he gets another error now, that he maybe fixed it. `116101115116116` would translate to `testt` then.

Comment: @Osiris Now it works, but if I enter test, I get "testt"...

Comment: @those who made my code more readable That could never happen with Python, where there is a defined way how you have to indent your code to make it work... I guess I´ll have to get used to this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char str[1]` cannot hold any strings longer than 0, as the definition of C strings is an array of characters terminated by one null character. Therefore, your `str` array must be 2 bytes in order to contain both at least one `char` and 1 null character (`'\0'`). This is most likely what's ailing you.

I touched up on your code and got it to work the way you want, but you will have to fine tune the abnormalities that you find unwanted. Read the notes I left by the following adjustments:

> `char str[1] -> char str[2]`

Size must be at least 2 to accommodate both a char & a null terminated character (`\0`).

> `sprintf(str, "%d", a) -> sprintf(str, "%c", a)`

You were formatting your char as an `int`, hence why you were getting numbers instead of text when you later concatenated the string.

Lastly, your final character was being printed twice because of this:

```
if (a != EOF && a != ' ' && a != '\t' && a != '\n')
    sprintf(str, "%c", a);
strcat(w, str);
```

`strcat(w, str);` is not inside the scope of the `EOF` check, so it concatenates the last character anyway.

Output:

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int word = 1, line = 1, a = 0;
    char str[2], w[70];
    strcpy(w, " ");
    while (a != EOF) {
        a = getchar();
        if ((a != EOF) && (a == ' ' || a == '\t' || a == '\n')) {
            ++word;
            if (a == '\n')
                ++line;
        }
        if (a != EOF && a != ' ' && a != '\t' && a != '\n') {
            sprintf(str, "%c", a);
            strcat(w, str);
        }
        if (a == ' ' || a == '\t' || a == '\n' || a == EOF) {
            printf("%d.%d%s\n ", line, word, w);
            strcpy(w, " ");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That was what the people in the comments said as well. That did solve the original problems, but there is still the problem that it prints the last letter of a word two times (e.g `test` becomes `testt`).

Comment: You will find that it doesn't do that anymore. Try running the code.

Comment: Maybe because of the changed position of the `\n`. That might actually have changed something.

Comment: Be sure to check my post again, especially the last part. I explain why the last character was being printed twice. The newline escape shift was just for readability.

Comment: `char str[1]` can hold the empty string.

Comment: @JohannesJ Oh, sorry, I think I didn`t read it carefully enough. So it was just some `{}` I forgot. I didn`t copy your code, but correct mine, and since someone wrote something different here (I think that answer was deleted or edited), which didn´t work, but used a command that only needs one line, I didn´t notice I forgot the brackets the first I tried writing the program.

Comment: @giusti Which empty string and why would you ever need an empty string? A "single"-character string always consists out of to characters: the for people important character and `\0`.

Comment: The empty string would be `""`. As an array, it is `{0}` or, equivalently, `{'\0'}`. You have certainly used it before. If you initialize an array of 10 chars with zero, you have the empty string.